# Why did this trigger XSS?

Tags: security, xss, client-side

I just found this on xssed.com , and if anyone could explain me why is alert show [here](http://iclass.eccouncil.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=15&Itemid=25&%2522%253e%253c%2573%2563%2572%2569%2570%2574%253e%2561%256c%2565%2572%2574%2528%252f%2558%2553%2553%252f%2529%253c%252f%2573%2563%2572%2569%2570%2574%253e=XSS-ME)

Why %25 and then hex value , I tried just %hexvalue and nothing happens , how does %25 helps .
Thanks ,satisfy my curiosity...

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/ is a good forum for questions like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full XSS payload is:

> %2522%253e%253c%2573%2563%2572%2569%2570%2574%253e%2561%256c%2565%2572%2574%2528%252f%2558%2553%2553%252f%2529%253c%252f%2573%2563%2572%2569%2570%2574%253e=XSS-ME

If you perform a single url-decode you get the following:

```
%22%3e%3c%73%63%72%69%70%74%3e%61%6c%65%72%74%28%2f%58%53%53%2f%29%3c%2f%73%63%72%69%70%74%3
```

If you perform a 2nd URL decode again you get the payload:

```
"><script>alert(/XSS/)</script>=XSS-ME
```

This is a doulbe-url encoded payload.  when `%2522` is url-decoded it becomes: `%22` because hex-25 is a %,  and when it is url decoded again it becomes `"`.

Comment: Thanks , and one more question with & it's ok without & nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer.  Some googling got me the answer.  Thanks anyway.

http://www.criticalsecurity.net/index.php/topic/8870-bypassing-phps-urlencode/